# Separate decode/encode interfaces or in one interface

Tags: java, api, oop, fluent-interface

I'm creating an implementation that performs conversion from one form to another.

The design problem I am facing now is whether the Encoder and Decoder API should be in one interface or in separate ones. e.g. Apache MINA uses [separate interfaces](http://mina.apache.org/report/1.1/apidocs/org/apache/mina/filter/codec/package-summary.html)

I am currently doing something like this:

```
interface Convertor
{
    A encode( B b );

    B decode( A a );
}
```

The rationale for putting them in one interface is that you can centralize the implementations and fix any protocol changes in one place. Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having separate interfaces doesn't mean you can't centralize the implementation. For example you could have one class implement both interfaces. Or each class could reference a common class which implements the protocol.

So what I'd do is have separate interfaces, and at least to begin with, have one class implement both. So the implementation is shared, but user code sees the encoder and decoder as separate and independent concepts.

Comment: How do you put the protocol spec in one class and have an encoder and decoder derive from it?

Comment: @EricStalnik well, this is of course completely abstract, so it's hard to say anything specific, but often, the protocol itself defines a number of data structures and common operations, which can all be defined in one common class. The encoder and decoder can then just use those data structures and call those operations, while presenting a simplified "encoder" or "decoder" interface.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware you're saying it's possible. What I'm asking is how the heck do you do it? What kind of design pattern would be used. I'm clueless.

Comment: @EricStalnik what do you mean? I just described how I would do it. You don't need a design pattern, it is possible to just write code which does what you need in the way that you want.

Answer (score 3):

Only thing is that you usually have one code part that will use the decoder and a separate using the encoder. So a change to the encoding part of the interface will force an unnecessary recompile of the decoding part and vice versa.

True for c/c++ etc. with header file include.

Search for solid principles and see Interface Segregation Principle.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *could* have two separate interfaces, and then another interface which combines them. That would make it easier to be able to declare a single parameter for both, e.g.

```
private IEncoder encoder;
private IDecoder decoder;

public ThingWhichUsesEncodeAndDecode(IEncoder encoder, IDecoder decoder)
{
    this.encoder = encoder;
    this.decoder = decoder;
}

public ThingWhichUsesEncodeAndDecode(IEncoderDecoder both)
{
    this(both, both);
}
```

It really depends on how often you envisage using one part but not the other. Most of the time I find that encoding/decoding stuff I need both parts available, so I'd *probably* just declare one interface with both methods - but it does depend on the exact situation.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage of having them in the same interface is that it *forces* your implementations to be both encoders and decoders in a single class. This may seem reasonable currently, but it may not always be that way. So I would ask myself if this should be a requirement/is desirable ?

Comment: I would not decide based on that alone, as the implementation could be composed and just delegate to different classes implementing only the encoding and decoding respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Making them separate is a lot more flexible.  If you write separate interfaces you can always combine them into a third interface that you use whenever you need both encode **and** decode functions.

The reverse is not true.  If you write one interface from the start, you lose the flexibility to choose to include only encode **or** decode functions.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use them together, but some time not.
It depends on what is more natural for you.
BTW: If you define them separately you can still use them together
e.g.

```
interface Converter extends Decoder, Encoder { }
```

Answer (score 0):

consider not having a separate encoder/decoder interface but instead

```
interface Encodable
{
    Decodable encode();
}
interface Decodable
{
    Encodable decode();
}
class A implements Encodable;
class B implements Decodable;
```

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the application.

If normally you have an encoder and an decoder in the same binary, one interface is fine. If they are usually separate (e.g. a capture application only encoding, a management application only decoding), use separate interfaces.